# How to merge the jsonb datatype while doing an edit from

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

i am working on the spring boot application and using hibernate for database connection.I have an save-edit api which will update the record after user has edited some filed. Now since i have some json filed as will, which of Jsonb type in my postgresql and to support with the hibernate i have written some custom dilate.

Problem:
Now the problem is while saving the record for the first time json data get save properly into jsonb datatype column. But when i do the edit operation the same json does not updated and store empty value.

Help:
I need a help on how jsonb work when you try to do update operation.

Comment: How exactly did you write your custom dialect?

Comment: @Kayaman i have taken the reference of -  https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/  link to create my dialect